# For внутри создания массива

Tags: php

Создаю массив , внутри него цикл, но вылазит синтаксическая ошибка...

```
$data[] = [
   for ($i = 3; $i <= 34; $i++) {
       ''.$i.'' => $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$row)->getCalculatedValue(),
];}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting ']' in
>   /var/www/html/sale.php on line 21

Comment: И что вы хотели получить этим кодом?

Comment: Если что, то это часть кода

Answer (score 2):

Так, как вы написали, php не умеет

```
$temp = [];
for ($i = 3; $i <= 34; $i++) {
   $temp[$i] = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$row)->getCalculatedValue();
}
$data[] = $temp;
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не верен

Comment: Точно! Вот теперь, должно быть то, что у вас в вопросе

Comment: Вот таким образом массив создается корректно               $data[] = [
                    '3' => $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getCalculatedValue(),];

Comment: @АлексейМарченко, почему данный ответ не верен? Он совершенно правильный, а ваш вопрос составлен абсолютно некорректно и ваш код не соответствует синтаксису php.

Comment: $tmpfname = "/var/www/html/sale/Internet.xls";
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(1);
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

$data = [];
        for ($row = 16; $row <= 17; $row++) {
             $data[] = [
                    '3' => $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getCalculatedValue(),
             ];
        }

Comment: Вот код который удачно отрабатывает, но суть вопроса была в том чтобы за место  '3' => $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getCalculatedValue(), ]; можно было вставить цикл for

Comment: Давайте ка вы вместо кодов напишите в вопрос желаемую структуру массива

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [3] => 222171
            [9] => 213958

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 78492
            [4] => 72997